# Find Last Records Created In Database Without Knowing Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with a large number of tables and I want to run a script to bring back the last 10 records created and tell me what table they are created on.

Is this possible?

I have researched ways to find the latest record, but I needed to know the table involved and could only check one table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is -

1. Identify the database using
2. Use a Query on System Tables to get table names and creating timstamps .
3. For each table , run a query to fetch the last

MySQL provides the information_schema.tables table. You can query the UPDATE_TIME column to get the last modification time.

```
-- Step 1: Identify the MySQL database you are using
USE your_database_name;

-- Step 2: Get table names and creation timestamps
SELECT table_name, create_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema');

-- Step 3: For each table, fetch the last 10 records based on creation timestamps
-- Replace 'your_table_name' with each table name obtained from Step 2
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY create_timestamp_column DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Hi Ruchir, Thanks for your assistance. Is there a table where I can see the last modified date and time each table was modified?

Comment: You can query system tables or views to obtain information about the last modification date and time for tables.

Comment: Thanks Ruchir, I know the theory of what I am trying to do. Is there any possibility you could provide some syntax?

Comment: Check ans again.i have made some changes.

Comment: @Mark, if this is Oracle then no, there is no such dictionary view that will show you when a table was last modified. You can get an approximation from `dba_tab_modifications` but that's not meant for this purpose - stats gathering will zero it out. If you really need this kind of info, you'd need to either enable object auditing or put triggers on your tables. Chances are this isn't something you should be doing, though.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say about this

ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS describes tables accessible to the current user that have been modified since the last time statistics were gathered on the tables.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS.html#GUID-97603337-F3D8-4FC4-ADE0-E49200F6EE4E

The question was: Is this possible? So the answer would be NO!
You could use query like below but always have in mind that stats gathering will reset it.

```sql
Select TABLE_NAME
From all_tab_modifications 
Where TABLE_OWNER = 'SOME_OWNER' 
Order By TIMESTAMP Desc
Fetch First Row Only
/*
TABLE_NAME    
--------------
TBL           */
```

This will tell you which table has the last DML command done on, but not was it insert, update, delete. And the data is after last stats gathering...